# Are 'featured' questions also 'FAQ's?

Tags: discussion, meta, meta-faq, featured-tag

On [the homepage of Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), some community [faq](/questions/tagged/faq)s are shown on the right sidebar. However, apparently it also shows [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) questions.

> [image: 3 featured questions are also shown on the FAQ sidebar]

Before deciding if this is a bug, should featured questions be included (momentarily) in the FAQs?

Comment: It's been like this for years, maybe always. :-)